# HTML5 Canvas Ellipse Outline Becomes Distorted As Transformed

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ellipse

When I transform an HTML5 canvas context and draw an ellipse, as the transform becomes larger the ellipse outline becomes completely distorted. Below is some sample code and the results I see in both Firefox and Chrome.

```
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width=900 height=900></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 51, 255, 0.5)";
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, 1, -16776544, -16776916);
        ctx.ellipse(16776994, 16777316, 400, 400, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
    </script>
</body>
```

[Chrome Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcKia.png)

[Firefox Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/122hh.png)

Is there a way to fix the distortion, or is it somewhere documented that there are limits on canvas transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the limited precision of floating point numbers. There is not much you can do about it but to avoid really big and really small numbers.

With a pixel size of 0.1mm you are addressing a pixel that is near one mile from the origin (that's a very big screen).

I am not sure if the canvas rendering uses 32bit floats (thinking it does from your example and I know that webGL definitely uses floats) you need to do the transformations in javascript as it uses doubles 64bit which will give you a screen 9 orders (approx) greater (screen now size of the sun)

eg

```
var x = 16776544;
var y = 16776916;
var x1 = 16776234;
var y1 = 16776446;
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
x -= x1; // apply transform using doubles
y -= y1;
ctx.ellipse(x,y,100,100,0,0,Math.PI*2);
```